# Scala implicit conversion for type aliases

Tags: scala, type-alias, implicits

Define

```scala
type TA[T] = T => Int

implicit class TAOps[T](a: TA[T]) {
  def foo(): Unit = {println("TA")}
}

val ta: TA[Double] = x => x.toInt
```

Now,

```scala
ta.foo()
```

fails to compile with the message `value foo is not a member of ammonite.$sess.cmd1.TA[Double]`,

while the explicit call

```scala
TAOps(ta).foo()
```

prints `TA`. Why does the implicit conversion not work in the former case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implicit def is expecting a type that receives one type parameter, i.e. a `TA[T]`

Your declaration: `val ta: TA[Double] = ...` is a type it self, and doesn't take any type parameters. So the compiler will not use your implicit def to type check this.

Conclusion you have an implicit type conversion for a type that takes a type parameter and `TA[Double]` doesn't take any type parameters.

## Solutions:

### 1 - Replace the implicit type conversion to receive a `Function1`:

```
  implicit class TAOps[T](a: T => Int) {
    def foo: Unit = {
      println("TA")
    }
  }
```

### 2 - Use type lambdas:

```
  implicit class TAOps[T](a: ({type Alias = TA[T]})#Alias) {
    def foo: Unit = {
      println("TA")
    }
  }
```

Here the type you created is curried. So the compiler will now apply this implicit conversions to types that match, it is no longer expecting a type that receives 1 type parameter.

More on [Type Lambdas](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/12/05/type-lambdas.html)

Comment: Thank you, @pedromss, it works. I wasn't aware that the type parameters 'holes' play role in this scenario.

Comment: I too found out the hard way :P. Does this answer your question?

Comment: This explanation doesn't sound quite right. The type of `a` in `TAOps` is not a type expecting another type. It is `TA[T]` which is fully applied. If this was the case then it would fail for `trait TA[T] extends (T => Int)` too but it doesn't. The solutions are appropriate but there must be more to the reasoning why this doesn't work.